# How is the universal selector working here?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
* { font-weight: normal; }
#stockTicker { font: 12px Verdana; }
.corpName { font-weight: bold; }
.stockUp { color: red; }

<div id="section">
   NYS: <span class="corpName"><span class="stockUp">GE</span></span> +1.0 ...
</div>
```

Why does universal selector get the last say here when .corpName comes later in the styles and also has higher specificity?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zackgao/2q9Wh/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS specifies that the assigned value of a property comes from the cascade, inherited, or the property's initial value, in that priority order ([CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specified-value)).

Since `*` is applied to the `<span class="stockUp">` during the cascade the inherited value isn't considered.

Text *directly* inside the `<span class="corpName">` element would be styled as you'd expect since the `corpName` class would beat out the `*` during the cascade.

Comment: Does this not contradict what the OP is claiming?

Comment: This explanation confused me at first, until I realised which `<span>` you were talking about where. I've edited the answer a bit, I hope I haven't made it worse.

Comment: @IMSoP: It's definitely an improvement.

Comment: @slynagh: I don't think so. He's complaining about the text inside of the `<span class="stockUp">` not inheriting from the `<span class="corpName">` element. @IMSoP's edit should clarify.

Comment: Ah I see! well I'm mistaken then!

Comment: This is the real reason why using the universal selector is not recommended. Not some far-fetched reason like performance.

Answer (score 0):

That is because CSS will be overwritten if it has lower priority. A class selector has higher priority than * selector. In your example they both have font-weight, thus the one has higher priority will be taken. In your example, font-weight:bold is being inherited from .corpName, however, *'s CSS applies directly to the stockUp span

Comment: That is not the actual behavior. * has lower priority and that is the font-weight being taken.

Comment: Hi, Can you try to make your point clear? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The question is: why does the behavior of my code violate exactly the principle you just gave as an explanation?

Comment: can you create a sample in jsfiddle? Or include a working url. So I can see your problem

Comment: It's because you are nesting spans. You should write something like .corpName span{font-wieght:bold;}

Answer (score 0):

I would say your mental model is indeed wrong. The * selector is not shorthand for "all basic html tags", it means "all elements". (It is not applying the style to all classes and ids: a class is not an element, nor is an id).

I think what you really need is to use `body{font-weight: normal;}`

Comment: But thats already implied in the default stylesheet, the body would already have a `font-weight` of `normal`.

Comment: True, but the point is the OP is using `*` selector when `body` selector seems to be the behaviour they're after.